# How can I find out the index of the text in the Editor that was added/removed? (Xamarin, Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, editor

I have an Editor in which the text changes. I need to know the index of added/removed substring relative to the whole text.

For example, I have a line in Editor:
"Hello world!".
And I added in a substring "thanks" to it:
"Hello world!thanks".

How can I find out the substring index (in my example, "thanks") relative to the whole text?

**PS:** I am not suitable property "IndexOf", because it looks for the first variant, and I need to find the substring which was changed (its position).
And I'm working only with Android (Xamarin).

Comment: If IndexOf isn’t suitable then you probably need to research different text comparison algorithms for a better option.

Comment: For this to be possible, you must have stored in a variable the *previous* value of the text. (Otherwise, you don't know what to compare to.) Perhaps the Editor's `OnTextChanged` can help you store previous text. Given that previous text, a simple approach is to use `for` to loop through both strings together, until you find a character that is different.